# .bash_profile alias escape quotes?

Tags: bash, quoting, alias, profile

I want to add a simple alias to my .bash_profile but no matter what quote method I use, I get an error.

I want to add this to my profile `alias htdoc=cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/`. Despite what quotes I use, I get this error

```
-bash: alias: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/‘: not found

-bash: alias: ‘/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/‘“: not found

-bash: alias: ‘/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/‘: not found

-bash: alias: “/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/“: not found

-bash: alias: “/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/“‘: not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote characters you are using are special Unicode quotes, the `“` (*U+201C*, left double quotation mark) and `‘` (*U+2018* - left single quotation mark) -- probably resulting of a copy and paste?.

You should use one of the plain ASCII quote character instead:

```
alias htdoc='cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/'
```

or:

```
alias htdoc="cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/"
```

Comment: I was using Mac TextEdit. That may be the problem right there. I'll try nano. I'll let you know. Thanks.

Comment: That was it. I knew it was something simple. Stupid text editor!

Comment: Right! Something similar happens to me when I write in certain editors in the browser -- silly editors indeed. =)